# SQL Error saying that I have not specified a 3rd Parameter

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am developing a Java Restful Web Application. When I try to execute this SQL Query using JDBCTemplate it gives and error saying that,

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc] in context with path [/paf_project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select count(*) from customer where email = ? AND password = ? AND status = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3] with root cause
>   java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3

Here is my Function which I am going to get the row count of my table.

```
    public int userLogin(String un, String pw) {
        String status = "active";
        String sql = "select count(*) from customer where email = ? AND password = ? AND status = ?";
        int count = template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {un, pw, status}, Integer.class);

        if(count >= 1) {
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: Are you certain that this is the _exact_ code which generated the error?  Also, you might want to tell us what version of Spring you are using.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have edited the Exact error which I am getting. Using Spring Version 4.3.2

Comment: i have much doubt that this code causes the error status is defined here. You sure to saved the file correctly for compiling? And you are sure you are using and uploaded the correct program?